# JBoss Fuse - how to use different CXF version

Tags: jboss, cxf, jbossfuse

I need to use Apache CXF 3.0.+ on JBoss Fuse. JBoss has built in Apache CXF 2.7 libraries.

How to force Fuse to work with Apache CXF 3.0.+. How to make module that will use isolated CXF libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CXF Maven repository URL and then install the CXF feature.

So, for example, if you need to install CXF 3.0.0, then,

> features:addurl mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.0/xml/features

Then you can check if the repository is added,

> features:listrepositories

You should be able to see, the cxf-3.0.0 feature available.

Then, you can install it,

> features:install cxf-3.0.0